# How to fetch and console json date on Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to pull JSON data and display on my console just to see if its working. I am seeing an error message.

I am trying to fetch a Model with `id` 1:

```
var TeamModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/json/team.json'
});

//Create Team Model Instance with id of team
var teamModel = new TeamModel({
  id: 1
 });

//Fetch the json data
teamModel.fetch();
var director = teamModel.get('name');
```

Here is the JSON file :

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Sam",
    "img_small" : "images/sam.jpg",
    "location" : "NYC",
    "role" : "Director, Producer, & Writer",
}
```

This yields the following error :

`GET http://localhost:9000/json/team.json/1 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Did you verify following few points:  1) whether your http request is suceesful with 200 status?  2) Try to put success callback in fetch() method and see the response.

Comment: Status 200 reads ok. The get status 404 reads error.

Comment: teamModel.fetch({success: alert('success')}) resulted in success

Comment: The error reads "Cannot GET /json/team.json/1"

Comment: Ohh sorry I didn't observe you got error while GET call. You need to first fix the HTTP GET call request

Comment: @Murthy Same as above!

Comment: @Murthy the error goes away once I remove the {id: 1} parameter from the TeamModel instance.. Any ideas??

Comment: @Tohsi Can you put the code for declaration method syntax which is in controller along with RequestMapping path here. So that we can analyze what should be the request HTTP path

Comment: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/json/team.json/1
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Answer (score 1):

You should use `url`, not `urlRoot`:

```
var TeamModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/json/team.json'
});
```

Backbone uses `urlRoot` to generate resource URLs based on the operation you perform (`fetch`, `save`, `delete`) and Model `id`. When you fetch a single Model, the URL it generates is `urlRoot + '/' + id`.

Therefore when you attempt to `fetch` a Model with id `1`, the constructed URL is `/json/team.json/1`

If you set `url`, however, Backbone always uses that url. It does not change it based on operation or model attributes. This is the behaviour that you need, because you have a single static resource.